# Error with FancyBox grouped elements (Requested content cannot be loaded)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do an image group with fancybox (I'm also using twitter bootstrap, etc)

However I'm getting the following error when the FancyBox "popup" appears:

```
The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.
```

Here's a test case that reflects my issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet "type="text/css" media="screen"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="#">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="#">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="#">
                    <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".thumbnail").click(function(){
                        $("a.grouped_elements").fancybox();
                        });
                    });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you notice your missing a `ul` or `ol` around your `li`'s?

Comment: YEah I did haha, thanks. In my original HTML I don't have the error ( damn Cut & Paste)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the HREF to the picture like this:

```
        <a class="grouped_elements" rel="group1" href="http://placehold.it/90x90_BIG.jpg"">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt>
        </a>
```